# For a converging in distribution sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)<M$ prove $\mathbb{E}(\ln(1+{X_n}^2)$ converges

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to}X$. It is relatively easy to prove that $ \ln(1+X_n^2) \stackrel{d}{\to}\ln(1+X^2)$. I was hinted that given a bound M such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\space\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)<M$ then $\mathbb{E}(\ln(1+X^2_n))\to\mathbb{E}(\ln(1+X^2))$.

I have managed to prove that under these restrictions $\mathbb{E}(|X|)\leq M$ and intuitively I understand that the M bound ensures $X_n$ doesn't grow to infinity faster than its probability goes to zero and the ln should eliminate this effect. However I don't seem to find a direction to pursue to prove the statement above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My impression is that $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to}X$ typically denotes convergence "in distribution". That's not the same as convergence in probability - which do you mean to ask about?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right, I corrected my question. I meant convergence in distribution

Comment: You are also writing series for sequence and $\mathbb EX_n$ for $\mathbb E|X_n|$ (in the title).

Comment: @geetha290krm fixed. I didn't learn mathematics in english so I have terminology errors

Comment: No problem. English is not so important for Math.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln (1+a^{2}))=4 \ln ({1+a^{2})}^{1/4}\leq 4[\sqrt {(1+a^{2})^{1/4}}-1] \le 4|a|^{/2}$. This proves that $(E(\ln (1+X_n^{2}))^{2}$ is bounded. If $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution and $EY_n^{2}$ is bounded the $EY_n \to EY$. [This uses Uniform integrability and Shorohod Representation].

Comment: Why is the last sentence correct?
 If Yn→Y in distribution and EY2n is bounded the EYn→EY.
Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @prh22 If you have $Y_n \to Y$ a.s or in probability this follows by a theorem on Uniform intrgrability. It is proved in K L Chung's ' A course in Probability Theory'. The case of convergence in distribution requires Skorohod's Thorem which reduces the proof to a.s convergence case.

Comment: Skorohov requires that the space is separable, we don't necessarily have this assumption in the question. No?

Comment: @prh22 Your r.v.'s are real valued and Skorohod only requires separability of the real line.

Comment: What is true is: There exist r.v. 's $Y_n,Y$ such that $Y_n\sim \ln (1+X_n^{2}), Y\sim ln (1+X^{2})$ for al $n$ and $Y_n \to Y$ a.s. Note that $EY_n=E \ln (1+X_n^{2}), EY=E\ln (1+X^{2})$. @prh22

Comment: @prh22 None of the basic convergence theorems of measure/probability theory are valid under convergence in distribution. If you want to prove this result under just convergence in distribution  it is impossible to give an elementary proof.